# Is this Shirk/Kufr?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, kufr, kuffar, takfir

Assalamu Alaikum!
My mother was one time advising me not to spend to much time in the bathroom and was mocking me that I spend hours just rubbing my feet during wudhu.and she also said that dont close the tap again and again during wudhu and I laughed loudly at this. Would this be regarded as Kufr ? Or mocking wudhu or islam ?

Answer (score 0):

No it is just shaytan waswas..U are suffering from
Ignore him,he will surely make you doubt that you have done kufr shirk but only way to make him weak and get to rid of him is to ignore him.
And try to recite 4 QUL (last 4 surahs of quran often)

Answer (score 0):

Kufr = Close yourself (from the truth, which is Islam)/Deny (the truth, which is islam)

Shirk = Believe in something other than Allah سُبْحَانَهُ وَ تَعَالَى‎ (I hope you know what i mean by this)

From these 2 definition up there, It shouldn't be regarded as Shirk Or Kufr.

> Or mocking wudhu or islam ?

What makes you laugh, is it the Wudhu practice? or because of ur mum? Insha Allah if you don't have the intention to mock the practice, then it's not regarded as mocking Wudhu.

Wallahu a'lam. Hope that answers the question